# Why is throwing of move operation is ignored for one overload of std::vector::resize()?

Tags: c++, stdvector, move-semantics

In the C++ standard [vector.capacity](https://wg21.link/N4861) section, it defines two overloads for `resize()`. (see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)

This overload requires that the type T is `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable`:

```cpp
constexpr void resize(size_type sz);
```

The other overload requires that the type T is `CopyInsertable`:

```cpp
constexpr void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
```

Clause 16 of the mentioned section in the standard states for the first overload that:

> If an exception is thrown other than by the **move constructor** of a non-Cpp17CopyInsertable T there are no effects.

But for the second overload it states:

> If an exception is thrown there are no effects.

Throwing of the **move constructor** is not mentioned in the second overload. why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Throwing of the move constructor is not mentioned in the second overload. why?

Because the second overload requires the type to be CopyInsertable. Given that requirement, the case *"of a non-Cpp17CopyInsertable T"* doesn't exist for the second overload, so there is no need to mention that case.

Comment: In other words, in this overload, resize is supposed to prefer *copy* over a *throwing move*, anyway. Is this some sort of uniform "culture" we can see in other areas of the C++ standard, or is it just this specific case?

Comment: @Xlv "Prefer strong exception safety" is the uniform "culture" that you can see throughout the C++ standard. In this case, the strong exception safety can be achieved by using copy instead of potentially throwing move.